# iOS UIButton: how to stretch the background image so it fits the button width?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

Let's say I have this sprite for a `UIButton`:

[image]

I would like to know how I can stretch its center, so the button may look like this for a smaller button:

[image]

Or like this for a bigger one:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you should use content Mode.

content mode is

> Options to specify how a view adjusts its content when its size changes.

if you write programmatically,

```
        button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

[image]